# RDP from macOS to Windows PowerShell. Move cursor shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, windows, remote-desktop

I'm using Microsoft Remote Desktop on macOS to work on Windows Server 2012. I want to move cursor to begin of the line in PowerShell terminal window. The same way as I use ^E, ^A on mac's terminal (or linux).

Does anyone know any hotkey for this? Without remapping macOS keys?

I found that <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> make it quicker but it is not that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

RDP sends mostly-raw keystrokes through the connection. On approximately all terminals other than the default MacOS configuration (Windows, Linux, BSD, DOS, etc.), you can go to the start of the line with <kbd>Home</kbd> and to the end with <kbd>End</kbd>.

Of course, Mac laptops don't ship with those keys. However, Apple's external keyboards usually have them (unless they're compacted down to laptop-size, which misses some of the point of an external keyboard), or you can use a Windows keyboard. You may also be able to set up a chord with the keys you have that sends the target app the same keypress events as Home/End, which would work as long as the OS traps that chord before sending it through the RDP connection.

Comment: As you said I don't have these magic keys. Sorry I didn't specify that I'm using MacBook to work. External keyboard that's not what I'm looking for. But thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Home" Windows key === Fn+[left arrow key] Mac
"End" Windows key === Fn+[right arrow key] Mac
```